# .save() doesn`t save everything in model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is method in controller

```js
exports.shareProve = async (req, res) => {
    summ = 0; count = 0;
    company = await companyModel.findById(req.body.companyId);
    for(let i = 0; i < req.body.sum.length; i++) {
        if(req.body.sum[i] > 0) {
            count++
            summ += Number(req.body.sum[i]);
        }
    }
    if(company.shareholders.share[0] - summ < 0) {
        res.redirect('back');
    }
    else {
        for(let i = 0; i < req.body.sum.length; i++) {
            /*man = await personModel.findById(req.body.userId[i]);
            man.stocks.id.push(companyId);
            man.stocks.share.push(req.body.sum[i]);
            man.save();*/
            if(req.body.sum[i] > 0) {
                company.shareholders.users.push(req.body.userId[i]);
                company.shareholders.share.push(req.body.sum[i]);
                company.shareholders.share[0] -= req.body.sum[i];
            }
        }
        console.log(company.shareholders.share);
        //await company.updateOne({$set: {'shareholders.share.0': company.shareholders.share[0]}});
        await company.save();
        //res.redirect('back');
    }
}
```

And this is how my model looks like

```js
companySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: companyId,
    name: String,
    ownerId: {
        type: userId,
        ref: 'person'
    },
    users: {
        type: [userId],
        ref: 'person'
    },
    shareholders: {
        users: [{
            type: [userId],
            ref: 'person'
        }],
        share: [Number]
    },
    gameId: {
        type: gameId,
        ref: 'game'
    },
    balance: Number, //ссылка на таблицу счетов
    license: String, //ссылка на таблицу лицензий
    salary: Number
});
```

That is my company before this method

```
{
  "_id": "5e032e9164b0d61dc45a5ea5",
  "shareholders": {
    "users": [
      "5df7292e7d3bfb36c07e8cc5"
    ],
    "share": [
      100
    ]
  },
  "users": [],
  "name": "22222",
  "ownerId": "5df7292e7d3bfb36c07e8cc5",
  "gameId": "5dfe870e1a1d1a3c60b57ed0",
  "__v": 2
}
```

That is my company in db after this method

```
{
  "_id": "5e032e9164b0d61dc45a5ea5",
  "shareholders": {
    "users": [
      "5df7292e7d3bfb36c07e8cc5",
      "5df41befc518db3120f96199",
      "5df00801fa0b9a0d00e05f4f"
    ],
    "share": [
      100,
      14,
      18
    ]
  },
  "users": [],
  "name": "22222",
  "ownerId": "5df7292e7d3bfb36c07e8cc5",
  "gameId": "5dfe870e1a1d1a3c60b57ed0",
  "__v": 2
}
```

`console.log()` gives me [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kipuy.png)

But when I try to save changes in db, I have [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfaWa.png)

Without `company.updateOne()` it doesnt save me the first item in array. Why? I heard that `updateOne()` in that case is wrong, and I should use `save`. Maybe there are problems with object shareholders?

Comment: Please describe your problem ?

Comment: I want my model to save by company.save(), not using update.one(). Or, if this is unreal, want to find out why

Comment: can you share your full code ?

Comment: you want to save  shareholders data in company collection at first time??

Comment: that is full method and model

Comment: Before that method I have one userId and first item in share eq 100, in this method I want to change it`s value

Comment: please share collection of company at jsoneditor online ?

Comment: that are collections before and after

Comment: I want my model to save by company.save(), not using update.one(). Or, if this is unreal, want to find out why :: not save use because without reference we cannot update the existing record.

Comment: so how should I reference to that?

Comment: find with forEach use we can achieve that

Comment: forEach instead of my for()?

Comment: please use that code :
companyModel.findById(req.body.companyId).forEach(function(doc){
 
    let data = {_id:doc._id};
    companyModel.remove({_id: doc._id});
    companyModel.save(data);

})

Comment: companyModel.findById(...).forEach is not a function